# Ubuntu - Nvidia drivers causes weird behaviour

Tags: drivers, nvidia, uninstall

I installed the latest nvidia drivers after many dirty attemps (I'm not used to linux and using console to install drivers) and well, finaly aparently I made it.

One thing I noticed is that when I'm browsing the web, the pictures (like browsing facebook photos) appear a lot darker than they looked before installing the drivers.

Second thing is that part of UI controls of programs, like Mozilla, Netbeans and others just flicker and it is very uncomfortable because it is very often.

I am using UBUNTU 14.04 and I want to uninstall the nvidia drivers and use the default ones.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you installed nvidias driver for ubuntu:

Navigate to the directory you have stored the .run-file, there

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-linux*.run --uninstall
```

If you have saved your old configurations they can be restored in the process.

Comment: best replace the `*` with your specific version (you can use Tab to autocomplete)

Comment: Well I tried, then when everything uninstalled I just came to see a Black screen after the UBUNTU logo when rebooting.

After browsing for similar topics, I found that you have to do something with a xorg.conf inside a x11 folder, but I received a NOT FOUND error after trying it. I had to REINSTALL the nvidia drivers, screen is still flickering and pictures are appearing dark, it's time to give another try, something else to add?